# Find historical Yahoo Finance Quote Prices

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yql, yahoo-finance

I have a functioning jfiddle example i'm just looking to tweak it but, i'm stumped...
I have a two part question for this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maxmillien/qPVSy/

**Part 1)** is there a way to clear the search each time a new search is done? *Example*: my quote is "GOOG" and a random date range. but then, I want to search another quote say "AAPL" is there a way to erase / remove the previous prices & dates for the previous search for "GOOG".

**Part 2)** is there a way to prevent double clicks for the same dates? *Example*: do a search for the past two weeks... but click the button twice you'll see the same dates & prices show up. I would like to prevent that from happening.

here is the code:

```
var yqlURL="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
var dataFormat="&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

$(function() { //Load jQueryUI DatePicker by class name
    $( ".datePick" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'} );
});

$("#submit").click(function() {
    var symbol = $("#txtSymbol").val();
    var startDate=$("#startDate").val();
    var endDate=$("#endDate").val();

    var realtimeQ = yqlURL+"select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + symbol + "%22)%0A%09%09&"+ dataFormat;
    var historicalQ = yqlURL+"select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22"+ symbol +"%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%22"+ startDate +"%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%22"+ endDate +"%22"+ dataFormat;

    $(function() {
        $.getJSON(realtimeQ, function(json) {//YQL Request
            $('#symbol').text(json.query.results.quote.Name);//Assign quote.Param to span tag
            $('#bidRealtime').text(json.query.results.quote.BidRealtime);
        });
    });  
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON(historicalQ, function(json) {            
            $.each(json.query.results.quote, function(i, quote) {//loop results.quote object 
                $("#date").append('<span>' + quote.Date + '</span');//create span for each record
            });            
            $.each(json.query.results.quote, function(i, quote) { //new each statement is needed
                $("#closeValue").append('<span>' + quote.Close + '</span');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: just checking if you've seen my answer yet? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1) You can attach a `$.click()` to clicking in the #inputSymbol box and clear the text using `.val('')`. If you want, you can attach `$.click()` to an x symbol or something.

Part 2) To prevent double clicks, you can disable the button after the first click and then enable the button again once a field has input. `$("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");` and then  `$("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");`

> `$("#txtSymbol").click(function() {`
>         `$("#txtSymbol").val(''); // part 1`
>        `this.enableSubmit; // part 2`
>     `});`
>
> `var enableSubmit = function() {`
>     `$("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");`
>    `}`

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/enjolras/qPVSy/255/)